# Aggregating Cluster Analysis Results

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, aggregation

I want to write something about cluster analysis. I have started to read something about it and I faced with a concept which is called ''Aggregating''. What does it mean for cluster analysis? Do I have to use it? And I guess, researchers prefer to use hierarchical cluster analysis for aggregating. Generally, why do they prefer to use hierarchical cluster analysis for aggregating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_clustering):

> Consensus clustering has emerged as an important elaboration of the
>   classical clustering problem. Consensus clustering, also called
>   aggregation of clustering (or partitions), refers to the situation in
>   which a number of different (input) clusterings have been obtained for
>   a particular dataset and it is desired to find a single (consensus)
>   clustering which is a better fit in some sense than the existing
>   clusterings.

This seems to imply that you "cluster your clusters," using multiple input clusters obtained from your dataset to find a better-fitting overarching cluster for your particular data.  You essentially reconcile different clusters derived from different runs of your algorithm on the same data.

> Topchy et al. Defined *clustering aggregation* as a maximum likelihood estimation problem, and they proposed an EM algorithm for finding the consensus clustering.